# Accessing Subject Content Angular for Audio Player

Tags: angular, audio, rxjs, subject

Basically I'm implementing an Audio Player in Angular. I based the audio player off of [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/building-an-audio-player-app-with-angular-and-rxjs/). The only thing is I'm implementing a Jukebox, so the audio cannot be hard-coded in as it will change based on what the users queue. I researched my problem and most solutions involved using a Subject for streaming audio. I have a player component, which is serviced by AudioService for playback and CloudService for pulling in the files. When I try to observe the queue in PlayerComponent I'm getting an undefined error. Can anyone help me with this or if anyone has any better solutions could they please give me some pointers.

**player.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { StreamState } from '../_interfaces/stream-state';
import { AudioService } from '../_services/audio.service';
import { CloudService } from '../_services/cloud.service';
import { Song } from '../_interfaces/song';
import { Subject, PartialObserver, Observer } from 'rxjs';

const incoming = [{
  url:
    // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
    'https://ia801504.us.archive.org/3/items/EdSheeranPerfectOfficialMusicVideoListenVid.com/Ed_Sheeran_-_Perfect_Official_Music_Video%5BListenVid.com%5D.mp3',
  songName: 'Perfect',
  artist: ' Ed Sheeran'
},
{
  url:
    // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
    'https://ia801609.us.archive.org/16/items/nusratcollection_20170414_0953/Man%20Atkiya%20Beparwah%20De%20Naal%20Nusrat%20Fateh%20Ali%20Khan.mp3',
  songName: 'Man Atkeya Beparwah',
  artist: 'Nusrat Fateh Ali Khan'
},
{
  url:
    'https://ia801503.us.archive.org/15/items/TheBeatlesPennyLane_201805/The%20Beatles%20-%20Penny%20Lane.mp3',
  songName: 'Penny Lane',
  artist: 'The Beatles'
}];


@Component({
  selector: 'app-player',
  templateUrl: './player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player.component.scss']
})
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {

  files: any[] = [];
  state: StreamState;
  currentFile: any = {};
  constructor(
    public audioService: AudioService,
    public cloudService: CloudService
  ) {
    cloudService.postSongs(incoming);

    cloudService.getFiles().subscribe(files => {
      this.files.push(files);
    });

    this.audioService.getState().subscribe(state => {
      this.state = state;
    });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.cloudService.queue.next());
  }

  playStream(url) {
    this.audioService.playStream(url).subscribe(events => {

    });
  }

  pause() {
    this.audioService.pause();
  }

  play() {
    this.audioService.play();
  }

  stop() {
    this.audioService.stop();
  }

  next() {
    const index = this.currentFile.index + 1;
    const file = this.files[index];
    this.openFile(file, index);
  }

  previous() {
    const index = this.currentFile.index - 1;
    const file = this.files[index];
    this.openFile(file, index);
  }

  openFile(file, index) {
    this.currentFile = { index, file };
    this.audioService.stop();
    this.playStream(file.url);
  }

  isFirstPlaying() {
    return this.currentFile.index === 0;
  }

  isLastPlaying() {
    return this.currentFile.index === this.files.length - 1 ;
  }

  onSliderChangeEnd(change) {
    this.audioService.seekTo(change.value);
  }

}
```

**audio.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { StreamState } from '../_interfaces/stream-state';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AudioService {
  private stop$ = new Subject();
  private audioObj = new Audio();

  audioEvents = [
    'ended',
    'error',
    'play',
    'playing',
    'pause',
    'timeupdate',
    'canplay',
    'loadedmetadata',
    'loadstart'
  ];

  private state: StreamState = {
    playing: false,
    readableCurrentTime: '',
    readableDuration: '',
    duration: undefined,
    currentTime: undefined,
    canplay: false,
    error: false,
  };

  private stateChange: BehaviorSubject<StreamState> = new BehaviorSubject(
    this.state
  );

  private updateStateEvents(event: Event): void {
    switch (event.type) {
      case 'canplay':
        this.state.duration = this.audioObj.duration;
        this.state.readableDuration = this.formatTime(this.state.duration);
        this.state.canplay = true;
        break;
      case 'playing':
        this.state.playing = true;
        break;
      case 'pause':
        this.state.playing = false;
        break;
      case 'timeupdate':
        this.state.currentTime = this.audioObj.currentTime;
        this.state.readableCurrentTime = this.formatTime(
          this.state.currentTime
        );
        break;
      case 'error':
        this.resetState();
        this.state.error = true;
        break;
    }
    this.stateChange.next(this.state);
  }

  private resetState() {
    this.state = {
      playing: false,
      readableCurrentTime: '',
      readableDuration: '',
      duration: undefined,
      currentTime: undefined,
      canplay: false,
      error: false
    };
  }

  private streamObservable(url) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      // Play audio
      this.audioObj.src = url;
      this.audioObj.load();
      this.audioObj.play();

      const handler = (event: Event) => {
        this.updateStateEvents(event);
        observer.next(event);
      };

      this.addEvents(this.audioObj, this.audioEvents, handler);
      return () => {
        // Stop Playing
        this.audioObj.pause();
        this.audioObj.currentTime = 0;
        // remove event listeners
        this.removeEvents(this.audioObj, this.audioEvents, handler);
        // reset state
        this.resetState();
      };
    });
  }

  private addEvents(obj, events, handler) {
    events.forEach(event => {
      obj.addEventListener(event, handler);
    });
  }

  private removeEvents(obj, events, handler) {
    events.forEach(event => {
      obj.removeEventListener(event, handler);
    });
  }


  playStream(url) {
    return this.streamObservable(url).pipe(takeUntil(this.stop$));
  }

  play() {
    this.audioObj.play();
  }

  pause() {
    this.audioObj.pause();
  }

  stop() {
    this.stop$.next();
  }

  seekTo(seconds) {
    this.audioObj.currentTime = seconds;
  }

  formatTime(time: number, format: string = 'HH:mm:ss') {
    const momentTime = time * 1000;
    return moment.utc(momentTime).format(format);
  }

  getState(): Observable<StreamState> {
    return this.stateChange.asObservable();
  }
}
```

**cloud.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of, Subject, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Song } from '../_interfaces/song';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from '@environments/environment';

interface ResponseSongs {
  results: Song[];
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CloudService {
  queue: Subject<any>;
  private url = `${environment.apiUrl}/assets/songs.json`;

getFiles() {
    return this.queue.asObservable();
  }

addToQueue(song) {
    this.queue.next(song);
  }

clearQueue() {
  this.queue.next();
}


constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.queue = new Subject<Song[]>();
  }

  postSongs(incoming) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/songs/set`, incoming)
    .pipe(map(songs => {
      localStorage.setItem('songs', JSON.stringify(songs));
      this.queue.next(songs);
      return songs;
    }));
  }

  getSongs(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
    .pipe(map(response => this.queue.next(response)));
  }
}
```

**backend.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, mergeMap, materialize, dematerialize } from 'rxjs/operators';

let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || [];
const songs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('music')) || [];


@Injectable()
export class FakeBackendInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const { url, method, headers, body } = request;

        // wrap in delayed observable to simulate server api call
        return of(null)
            .pipe(mergeMap(handleRoute))
            .pipe(materialize())
            .pipe(delay(500))
            .pipe(dematerialize());

        function handleRoute() {
            switch (true) {
                case url.endsWith('/users/authenticate') && method === 'POST':
                    return authenticate();
                case url.endsWith('/users/register') && method === 'POST':
                    return register();
                    case url.endsWith('/users') && method === 'GET':
                    return getUsers();
                case url.match(/\/users\/\d+$/) && method === 'DELETE':
                    return deleteUser();
                case url.endsWith('/assets/songs.json') && method === 'GET':
                    return getSongs();
                case url.endsWith('/songs/set') && method === 'POST':
                      return setSongs(body);
                default:
                    // pass through any requests not handled above
                    return next.handle(request);
            }
        }

        // route functions

        function authenticate() {
            const { username, password } = body;
            const user = users.find(x => x.username === username && x.password === password);
            if (!user) {return error('Username or password is incorrect'); }
            return ok({
                id: user.id,
                username: user.username,
                firstName: user.firstName,
                lastName: user.lastName,
                venueName: user.venueName,
                token: 'fake-jwt-token'
            });
        }

        function register() {
          const user = body;

          if (users.find(x => x.username === user.username)) {
              return error('Username "' + user.username + '" is already taken');
          }

          user.id = users.length ? Math.max(...users.map(x => x.id)) + 1 : 1;
          users.push(user);
          localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));

          return ok();
      }

        function getUsers() {
        if (!isLoggedIn()) {return unauthorized(); }
        return ok(users);
      }

        function deleteUser() {
        if (!isLoggedIn()) { return unauthorized(); }

        users = users.filter(x => x.id !== idFromUrl());
        localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));
        return ok();
      }

        function setSongs(incoming) {
          const incomingSongs = incoming;
          localStorage.setItem('songs', JSON.stringify(incomingSongs));
          return ok();
        }

        function getSongs() {
          return ok(songs);
      }

        // helper functions

        // tslint:disable-next-line: no-shadowed-variable
        function ok(body?) {
            return of(new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body }));
        }

        function error(message) {
            return throwError({ error: { message } });
        }

        function unauthorized() {
          return throwError({ status: 401, error: { message: 'Unauthorised' } });
      }

        function isLoggedIn() {
          return headers.get('Authorization') === 'Bearer fake-jwt-token';
      }

        function idFromUrl() {
          const urlParts = url.split('/');
          // tslint:disable-next-line: radix
          return parseInt(urlParts[urlParts.length - 1]);
      }
    }
}

export const fakeBackendProvider = {
    // use fake backend in place of Http service for backend-less development
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: FakeBackendInterceptor,
    multi: true
};
```

**Error message**

```
PlayerComponent.html:10 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'songName' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (PlayerComponent.html:11)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:45294)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44277)
at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44594)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44272)
at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44565)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44278)
at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
```

Comment: What is the undefined error? Try to be more specific, and if you want complete coding solutions try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @ajsp I've added the error message and I'll check out codereview site, thanks

Comment: @Peilonrayz Point taken.